# UIBlurEffectStyleLight with IOS 7 Blur

Tags: ios, objective-c, blur, uiblureffect

I have an app that runs on IOS 7 and 8.  On 8 I use UIBlurEffect with UIBlurEffectStyleLight which creates a beautiful vibrant blur.  On IOS 7 I use IOS Blur library which seems very similar to UIBlurEffectStyleExtraLight in IOS 8.  This creates a more fuzzy / white looking blur effect.  Is there any way to make the IOS Blur (which is essentially just a UItoolbar overlay) on IOS 7, look more like UIBlurEffectStyleLight on IOS 8?

Thanks!

**EDIT**  I was able to get an identical image by using Apple's UIImage+ImageEffects category and using applyLightEffect.

```
#import "UIImage+ImageEffects.h"
self.menu.image = [self.menu.image applyLightEffect];
```

Leaving this question open for now in case there are solutions that work for real time as well.

[image: IOS 8 UIBlurEffectStyleLight]

[image: IOS 7 using IOS Blur]

Answer (score 0):

`UINavigationBar` was the best real-time blur solution available in iOS7, but it has its limitations (and from an architecture point of view is a pretty horrible roundabout way to just get a blurred background on your view). There are ways to create blur images using the Accelerate framework in iOS7, but you're not going to get real-time performance out of it, so if you're planning to blur something that is moving or changing, you're stuck with `UINavigationBar`.

You can change the tint of the `UINavigationBar` to make it not be so white, but you can't set it to a clear tint to get a more accurate pixel colour blur -- it's always going to be tinted with either white or black first before applying your tint colour.